# Обработка двумерного массива

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Программа должна по выбору пользователя осуществлять ввод исходной матрицы с клавиатуры или из файла (это у меня есть). Для этого программа должна содержать две соответствующие функции, указатель на одну из которых необходимо передавать в функцию для вычисления элементов массива Х. Данная функция должна вызывать через указатель одну из функций ввода элементов матрицы, производить вычисление элементов массива X в соответствии с заданием и возвращать указатель на этот массив. Кроме того, программа должна содержать функцию для вывода на экран и в файл  исходной матрицы и результирующего массива, а также рекурсивную функцию определения в соответствии с заданием величины Y.  В программе не должно быть глобальных переменных.
   У меня дана матрица А(5х5). Необходимо определить массив Х из 5 элементов, каждый из которых равен первому отрицательному элементу  соответствующей строки матрицы или нулю, если все элементы строки положительны. Определить величину Y, как индекс первого отрицательного элемента массива X. 
В моей программе есть "пример обработки матрицы", но я не уверена, что функция делает всё верно и у меня нет рекурсивной функции. Не понимаю как её сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define n 5
using namespace std;

void input_matrsam(int A[n][n])
{
    cout << "Введите элементы матрицы А:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> A[i][j];
}

void input_matr(int A[n][n])
{
    int i, j;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("in.txt", "r");
      if (fp)
        if (fp)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    fscanf(fp, "%d", &A[i][j]);
            fclose(fp);
        }
}  
//
// пример обработки матрицы 
//
int* mas(int(*a)[n], int* otr,
    void (*Process)(int[n][n]))
{
    int otr, i, j;
    Process(a);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        otr[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i][j] < 0)
            {
                otr[i] = a[i][j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void output(const int x[], const int a[][n])
{
    cout << "Массив А:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, cout << '\n')
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << '\t';
    cout << "Массив X:\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        cout << x[j] << ' ';
}
int main()
{
   setlocale( LC_ALL, "Rus" ); 
   int a[n][n], x[n], y;
   void (*Process)(int[n][n]);
       cout << "Ввод матрицы:\n1. С клавитуры\n2. Из файла\n";
       int c;
       do
           cin >> c;
   while (c != 1 && c != 2);
   // Присваивание указателю адреса одной их функций:
   switch (c)
   {
   case 1: Process = &input_matr;
       break;
   case 2: Process = &input_matrsam;
       break;
   }
   output(mas(a, x, Process), a);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рекурсивная функция поиска `Y`: `serchingY()`. Но вначале не правильно прочел условие и в качестве бонуса рекурсивное заполнение массива `X`.

```
#include <iostream>

void search(int* matrixA, int* arrayX, int matrixNoRows, int matrixNoColumns)
{
    if (matrixNoRows == 0)
        return;

    int number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixNoColumns; ++i)
        if (number > *(matrixA + (matrixNoRows - 1) * matrixNoColumns + i) ){
            number = *(matrixA + (matrixNoRows - 1) * matrixNoColumns + i);
            break;
        }
    arrayX[matrixNoRows - 1] = number;
    search(matrixA, arrayX, matrixNoRows - 1, matrixNoColumns);
}

void searchingY(int* array, int arraySize, int& y, int position = 0)
{
    if (position == arraySize){
        y = -1; // если нет отрицательных чисел в массиве, то y = -1 
        return;
    }
    if (*(array + position) < 0){
        y = *(array + position) ;        
        return;
    }
    searchingY(array, arraySize, y, ++position);
}



int main() {
    std::cout << "input number of rows:\n"; //если у вас  матрица квадратная, то достаточно только одной переменной
    int rows, columns;
    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cout << "input number of columns:\n"; //если у вас  матрица квадратная, то этой строки...
    std::cin >> columns;   // ...и этой строки не надо как и переменной columns. Вместо нее везде пишите rows     

    int matrixA[rows][columns];
    int arrayX[rows];
    // далее в зависимости от метода ввода используете функцию заполнения матрицы
    // ...

    search((int*)matrixA, arrayX, rows, columns);    

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)     // проверка содержимого arrayX
        std::cout << arrayX[i] << '\t'; // этот цикл
    std::cout << std::endl;            // можно удалить

    int y;
    searchingY(arrayX, rows, y);
    std::cout << "Y : " << y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как тогда правильно вызвать эти функции, чтобы программа работала верно?

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? В примере же все указано: вместо цифр можно вставлять переменные размерности матрицы и массива. Приведите пример, где именно непонятно.

Comment: Получается, где начинaется int main() у меня происходит выбор ввод матрицы с клавиатуры или из файла. Затем идёт вызов функций. И вот здесь мне непонятно: как заменить уже готовую матрицу на то, чтобы пользователь сам вводил числа этой матрицы.

Comment: судя по условию задачи, вы заранее знаете размер матрицы, следовательно, либо вы ее хардкодите [размерность матрицы], как это сделано в вашем примере: `#define n 5`, но лучше через `const int ROWS = 5` , `const int COLUMNS= 5'. Но т.к. у вас запрещены глобальные переменные, то просто объявите их в теле `main()`. Либо если размерность матрицы в разных вариантах меняется, тогда вводите размерность через ввод с клавиатуры. И пишите вместо моей матрицы matrixA[rows][columns]. А потом ее заполняйте с помощью ваших функций. Я сейчас немного подправлю код...